# Use of the word will as a noun

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to produce a intent that will recognise a sentence such as
"I can't find the probate of a Will". Dialogflow does not seem to recognise 'will' in the sentence even when this sentence is in the training phrases and marked as an entity. Is there a way to get Dialogflow to recognise this word other than something like a proposition which can be ignored?

Comment: Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57021319/edit) with some screen shots that illustrate how you have the Intent and Entity setup in this case that it is not being recognized?

Comment: Please provide more details on how you have configured dialog flow so far.

Comment: It seems to work now so I would like to withdraw the query